# Qué es base64, donde se alojan los archivos creados

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64

Me interesa saber qué es base64, ya que encontré un script que recibe una imagen y la convierte en un link **data:image** y esta se puede visualizar en cualquier lado de internet sin subirla a un servidor.

¿Por qué? qué es lo que hace poder ser mostrada en cualquier lado sin subirla a un servidor.

Donde se alojan, que cantidad de imagenes se pueden generar, navegadores que lo soportan, el tiempo de vida de los archivos y si solo se puede con imagenes.

```
    function readFile(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

        var reader = new FileReader();



        reader.onload = function (e) {

            var filePreview = document.createElement('img');

            filePreview.id = 'file-preview';

            //e.target.result contents the base64 data from the image uploaded

            filePreview.src = e.target.result;

            console.log(e.target.result);



            var previewZone = document.getElementById('file-preview-zone');

            previewZone.appendChild(filePreview);

        }



        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

    }

}



var fileUpload = document.getElementById('file-upload');

fileUpload.onchange = function (e) {

    readFile(e.srcElement);

}
```

Comment: base64 es una codificación, es como si en vez de poner 'a' pusieras 'b' y así sucesivamente, cuando pones un data.image realmente estás pasando la imágen allí mismo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Que es base64?**
Simple base64 es una cadena de texto 'Variable string' que contiene toda la información de la imagen y todos sus datos.

> Si el contenido de tu imagen en la variable base64: '**e.target.result**'

Cuando la utilizas puede funcionar como un enlace porque en si es toda la imagen/U otro archivo que hayas convertido en base64.
Incluso lo puedes guardar en una base de datos y llamarlo en JavaScript y colocarlo en un **src** de una etiqueta **img**.

> Aunque no recomiendo guardar base64 en una base de datos pues es un algo lento.